# parallelize a function that fill missing values from duplicates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a product data frame that consists of 1838379 rows that have description image_url, eans, and product name
this dataset has duplicates in the product name I am trying to fill the nan values in description image_url, eans with the duplicated values in product name so i implemented this function

```
def fill_descriptions_images_ean_from_duplicates(row,train):
    import pandas as pd
    duplicated_rows = train.loc[train['product_name'] == row["product_name"]]
    if not duplicated_rows.empty:

        
        descriptions=duplicated_rows["description"].dropna()
        if not descriptions.empty:
            description=list(descriptions)[0]
            train.loc[train['product_name'] ==  row["product_name"], 'description',] = train.loc[train['product_name'] ==  row["product_name"], 'description'].fillna(description)

        images=duplicated_rows["image_url"].dropna()
        if not images.empty:
            
            image=list(images)[0]
            train.loc[train['product_name'] ==  row["product_name"], 'image_url',] = train.loc[train['product_name'] ==  row["product_name"], 'image_url'].fillna(image)
        

        eans=duplicated_rows["ean"].dropna()
        if not eans.empty:
            ean=list(eans)[0]
            train.loc[train['product_name'] ==  row["product_name"], 'ean',] = train.loc[train['product_name'] ==  row["product_name"], 'ean'].fillna(ean)
```

when I use apply it takes forever to execute so I tried using Pandaralele but pandaralele  doesn't support the lambda function and it tells me that the fill_descriptions_images_ean_from_duplicates is not defined

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
import psutil

psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)

pandarallel.initialize()
train.parallel_apply(lambda row: fill_descriptions_images_ean_from_duplicates(row, train), axis=1)
```

so i tried using dask but nothing happend either the progressbar is stuck

```
def process_partition(df_partition,train):
    df_partition.apply(lambda row: fill_descriptions_images_ean_from_duplicates(row, train), axis=1)
    return df_partition
```

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
dask_train = dd.from_pandas(train, npartitions=7)
dask_df_applied = dask_train.map_partitions(lambda row: process_partition(row, train),meta=train.dtypes)
with ProgressBar():
    train=dask_df_applied.compute()
```

sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate random data
data = {
    'product_name': ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product B', 'Product C', 'Product D'] * 20,
    'description': np.random.choice([np.nan, 'Description'], size=100),
    'image_url': np.random.choice([np.nan, 'image_url'], size=100),
    'ean': np.random.choice([np.nan, 'EAN123456'], size=100)
}

# Create the DataFrame
train= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I go to parallelism as a last resort. Can you explain and share sample data of what you have and what you would like to have as an outcome? I think vectorisation is all you need.

Comment: i cannot provide the data itself it s confidential but i provided an example

Comment: It looks like your code gets the first non-na value for each column grouped by the product name? e.g. `train.groupby('product_name', sort=False).transform('first')`

Comment: yes i get the first non null value and fill with it

Comment: Yes, the `transform('first')` should do that in one step e.g. `train.fillna(train.groupby('product_name', sort=False).transform('first'))`

Comment: it didnt work  ``` train.groupby('product_name', sort=False).transform('first')```  returns all the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the best thing I could find it reduces the time to 15 minutes

```
train['description'] = train.groupby('product_name')['description'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.dropna().iloc[0]) if x.notnull().any() else x)
train['image_url'] = train.groupby('product_name')['image_url'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.dropna().iloc[0]) if x.notnull().any() else x)
train['ean'] = train.groupby('product_name')['ean'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.dropna().iloc[0]) if x.notnull().any() else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/) library. It has much more functionality that `pandarallel` and also supports `lambda` functions

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas

#initialize parallel-pandas
ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=16, split_factor=4, disable_pr_bar=True)

# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1_000, 100))) 

df.head()
      0            1            2          3            4
0   0.525561    0.342411    0.546397    0.016009    0.810697
1   0.206626    0.794180    0.856513    0.492897    0.446797
2   0.795895    0.790188    0.651192    0.196008    0.415761
3   0.214247    0.307092    0.873755    0.518329    0.166529
4   0.059282    0.306833    0.137190    0.206785    0.314207

#parallel analogue of apply method
#just as an example
df.p_apply(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)

0      0.525561
1      0.206626
2      0.795895
3      0.214247
4      0.059282
         ...   
995    0.490312
996    0.239747
997    0.893300
998    0.395077
999    0.710804
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```